# How to create cloud formation using IAM roles in AWS Java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, aws-cloudformation

I'm very new to [Amazon cloud formation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) technique My current task is to create a **stack** on [Amazon Cloud Formation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) using [Java SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java) with an IAM role. On the **AWS CLI**, I am able to create the amazon cloud formation by adding an additional parameter *--profile* . I have created a profile with the *role-arn* in the config file as mentioned in the following [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-cli.html).

Now I want to implement the same using [Java SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java) from AWS . My ***Stack* *request*** in Java is as follows

```
CreateStackRequest r = new CreateStackRequest();
r.withStackName(getStackName());
r.withParameters(getParameters());
r.withTemplateURL(getTemplate());
r.withCapabilities(getCapabilities());
r.withRoleARN(getArnRole());
```

My ***Amazon cloud formation*** client initialisation is as follows

```
amazonClient=AmazonCloudFormationClientBuilder.standard()
             .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
             .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
             .build();
```

But I am unable to create an amazon cloud formation as it is giving me the following **error**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.cloudformation.model.AmazonCloudFormationException:
User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:user/xxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole
on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/xxxxxxxx (Service: AmazonCloudFormation;
Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: xxxxxxxxxx)
```

Can somebody let me know what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

**AWS CLI**

I have installed AWS SDK on my local windows system. To execute the cloud formation command on the aws cli I am doing the following

```
aws cloudformation create-stack  --stack-name xxxxx
--template-url xxxxxxxx 
--capabilities "CAPABILITY_IAM" --parameters xxxxxx --profile xxxxxxx
```

The `template and parameters` are stored in json format in a s3 bucket. When I ran the above command line I got the following `output`

```
{
  "StackId": "xxxxxxx"
}
```

**AWS Java SDK**

I have created a Java code which take the following as command Line arguments

```
--stack-name xxxxxx--template-url xxxxx 
--capabilities "CAPABILITY_IAM" --parameters xxxxx 
--profile xxxxxx --access-key xxxxxxx --secret-key xxxxxxxx
```

My `AWS config file` is as follows

```
 [default]
 output = json
 region = us-east-1
 [profile xxxxx]
 role_arn = arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/xxxxxxxx
 source_profile = default
 region = us-east-1
```

My `AWS credentials file` is as follows

```
 [default]
 aws_access_key_id = xxxxxx
 aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxx
 [profile xxxxxx]
 aws_access_key_id = xxxxxx
 aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxx
```

In the ***Amazon cloud formation*** client `initialisation`, I have tried the following

```
 1. amazonClient=AmazonCloudFormationClientBuilder.standard()
             .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
             .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
             .build();

 2. BasicAWSCredentials  credentials=new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey,secretKey); 
   AmazonCloudFormationClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new 
   AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).build();
```

In both the `initialisations`, I have got the same **error**.

Comment: you need permissions in your ~/.aws/credentials folder to achieve the task. some reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

Comment: @chenrui How to do I give permissions for that file in a windows machine?

Comment: The permission (IAM role) is associated with your AWS account ID,

Comment: Where is this code running from? Local or any EC2 instance?

Comment: @kosa Local machine

Comment: Same profile worked for CLI and but not working for SDK? are you sure you are using correct profile? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html

Comment: @kosa I have two profiles in my config file. One is default and other is xxxxx. How do I pass that in the AWS Java SDK in create stack request?

Comment: Pass what? Which profile you used for CLI? SDK documentation has details on how to use a specific profile when you more than one profile.

Comment: @kosa can you provide the link of the documentation?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.html   you need to specify the name of the profile as param, otherwise default will be used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147863/discussion-between-shubhamagiwal92-and-kosa).

Comment: that didn't work

Comment: That didn't work is blanket statement. What you have tried & what was the message you got will help in understanding the issue.

Comment: @kosa See my edit

Comment: There are couple of things here, 1) Profile picked up, but that pickedup profile has NOT enough permissions 2) Which profile SDK picked? You blocked the profile details, but can you confirm that SDK profile picked has enough permissions? 3) The second approach with BasicCredentials? key and secret, did you give path (or) you used direct credentials in code? and what was the output in that case?

Comment: @kosa I fixed the issue. Basically I didn't have enough permissions to create cloud formation. Once I had the permissions, the issue got resolved.

Comment: Glad to know you were able to resolve the issue. Add it as answer and accept it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Cloud Formation stack by using the AWS CloudFormation Java API V2. To run this code, you must place your template into a S3 bucket. Also, you must setup a IAM role with CloudFormation, S3, and EC2 permissions.

The following code successfully creates a Stack.

```
// snippet-start:[cf.java2.create_stack.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudformation.CloudFormationClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudformation.model.CloudFormationException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudformation.model.CreateStackRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudformation.model.OnFailure;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudformation.model.CreateStackResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudformation.model.Parameter;
// snippet-end:[cf.java2.create_stack.import]

/**
 *  To run this example, you must have a valid template that is located in a S3 bucket.
 *  For example:
 *
 *  https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/CloudFormationTemplate.yml
 *
 *  Also, the role that you use must have CloudFormation permissions as well as S3 and EC2 permissions. For more information,
 *  see "Getting started with AWS CloudFormation" in the AWS CloudFormation User Guide.
 *
 */

public class CreateStack {

   public static void main(String[] args) {


        String stackName = "mystack2";
        String roleARN = "arn:aws:iam::<enter ARN Role>";
        String location = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/<BUCKET NAME>/CloudFormationTemplate.yml";

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        CloudFormationClient cfClient = CloudFormationClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        try {
            
            // Ensure you set the correct key name and value
            Parameter myParameter = Parameter.builder()
                    .parameterKey("KeyName")
                    .parameterValue("keypair1")
                    .build();

            CreateStackRequest stackRequest = CreateStackRequest.builder()
                .stackName(stackName)
                .templateURL(location)
                .roleARN(roleARN)
                .onFailure(OnFailure.ROLLBACK)
                .parameters(myParameter)
                .build();

            CreateStackResponse stackResponse = cfClient.createStack(stackRequest);
            System.out.println("The stack Id value is " +stackResponse.stackId());

        } catch (CloudFormationException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
}
```